# Why is my fixed width layout shrinking when using the developer tools inside the browser?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm currently using google chrome browser developer tools to resize my webpage as I create it. I ran a test with a single  element which I set the width to 900px. When I resize the page inside the browser using developer tools the div element shrinks with the page as if its responsive. From experience when you have a fixed width the element should "run" off of the screen once the screen decreases pass the elements size and make the window scroll left and right but instead the element starts to become responsive and it doesn't "run" off of the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Page Shrinkage</title>
        <style>
            div{
                width: 900px;
                background-color: blue;
                height: 300px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <div>
            1
        </div>

    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the exact code?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#). Asking why something doesn’t work without showing what you’re doing isn’t going to get you anywhere.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Testing Page Shrinkage</title>
        <style>

            div{
                width: 900px;
                background-color: blue;
                height: 300px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <div>
            1
        </div>

    </body>
    
</html>

Comment: @rayhatfield I'm new to stackoverflow guys. My apologizes if my comments/ code does't look presentable

Comment: Add it to the question, please.

Comment: I add it to the question

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you want graphically?

Comment: I placed the above code in the text editor and tested it in the browser using the developer tools. I then expand and retract the page to see if the <div> element is fixed but it moved as if it's responsive. It shouldn't be moving if I have a fixed width for that element.

Comment: Hello, there doesn't seem to be wrong with the code itself. I ran it on a codepen and it functions as expected by exceeding smaller widths and creating a horizontal scroll. Is there anything with your environment that could have affected this functionality? When you examine the element in dev tools and resize the screen, does the width value change dynamically?

Comment: Hey @xenvi, I don't think anything is wrong with my environment. I use VSCode and I haven't made any changes to the settings. I'll probably try codepen to run tests.